# Recharging of Inverter Batteries

Tags: solar-cell, solar-energy, solar-charge-controller

Is it possible for some reason I can be able to safely connect two charge controllers (who draw their solar power from the same solar panel array) to charge separate/independent batteries?

(It is to be noted that the batteries each discharges independent of one another at different times). Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible for some reason I can be able to safely connect two charge controllers (who draw their solar power from the same solar panel array) to charge separate/independent batteries?

Generally, yes.
There may be some interaction in some cases but two controllers fighting for energy is little different than a panel providing variable energy as insolation changes.

It is possible that PWM noise from one controller MAY affect the other.
Worst case, adding a large capacitor at the panel output may be useful.